# Conditional Entropy in Markov Chain

Tags: probability, markov-chains, conditional-probability, information-theory

Suppose that $X\rightarrow Y\rightarrow Z$ is a Markov chain with $X,Y$ and $Z$ are all Bernoulli variables, and we have the following assumptions:

- Between $X$ and $Y$: The joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ are known, specifically $X=Y\oplus S_1$ for $S_1\sim \text{Bern}(p)$ and $X\sim \text{Bern}(a)$;
- Between $Y$ and $Z$: The conditional entropy $H(Y|Z)=C$.

Then for $X$ and $Z$, can we compute the conditional entropy $H(X|Z)$?

Comment: What did you try and where are you stuck?

Comment: @stochasticboy321 It actually was the confusion when I read the paper of [Mrs Gerber's Lamma](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=1055107). Corollary 4 states that for the assumption in the question above, $H(Y|Z)\geq C$ implies $H(X|Z)\geq H(C_1)$ where $C_1=p*h^{-1}(C)$, but did not provide the condition of equality. Based on the theorem from which the corollary is derived, $H(X|Z)= H(C_1)$ when $H(Y|Z)= C$. But I found it is not so straightforward. I drew an information diagram for the Markov chain, and found that it is hard to determine the exact value of $H(Y|Z)$.